# ng build is not creating new index file in dist folder

Tags: angular, angular-builder

I am using the Fuse template to start a new project. I have done this with no problems before. This time, when starting with a skeleton app, I created a new component and module and it was running through ng serve with no problems. When I went to build and deploy to firebase hosting, I noticed that while it built a Fuse folder in /dist, there was no index file created in /dist. Any ideas as to why this happened?

Here is the output from it.

```
Warning: Entry point '@swimlane/ngx-dnd' contains deep imports into                 
'/Users/joshuafoxworth/Sites/CADWOLFv9/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/core'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
10% building 4/4 modules 0 active(node:89554) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
<w> [webpack.Progress] 35955ms building
<i> [webpack.Progress] 110ms finish module graph
<i> [webpack.Progress] 32ms chunk graph
<i> [webpack.Progress] 25ms advanced chunk optimization
<i> [webpack.Progress] 23ms before module ids
<i> [webpack.Progress] 16ms module id optimization
<i> [webpack.Progress] 85ms hashing
<i> [webpack.Progress] 134ms chunk assets processing
<w> [webpack.Progress] 5589ms after chunk asset optimization
<i> [webpack.Progress] 535ms emitting
Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
ES5 bundle generation complete.

chunk {polyfills} polyfills-es2015.js, polyfills-es2015.js.map (polyfills) 187 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills-es5} polyfills-es5.js, polyfills-es5.js.map (polyfills-es5) 830 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {main} main-es2015.js, main-es2015.js.map (main) 3.65 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {main} main-es5.js, main-es5.js.map (main) 3.72 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime-es2015.js, runtime-es2015.js.map (runtime) 6.16 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime-es5.js, runtime-es5.js.map (runtime) 6.16 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles-es2015.js, styles-es2015.js.map (styles) 3.95 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles-es5.js, styles-es5.js.map (styles) 3.96 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor-es2015.js, vendor-es2015.js.map (vendor) 6.68 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor-es5.js, vendor-es5.js.map (vendor) 7.72 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-07-11T21:32:17.597Z - Hash: 724efdf549e68fc2e039 - Time: 63604ms

WARNING in /Users/joshuafoxworth/Sites/CADWOLFv9/src/hmr.ts depends on '@angularclass/hmr'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

WARNING in /Users/joshuafoxworth/Sites/CADWOLFv9/src/app/app.module.ts depends on 'hammerjs'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

WARNING in /Users/joshuafoxworth/Sites/CADWOLFv9/src/@fuse/components/navigation/navigation.service.ts depends on 'lodash'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
```

Angular JSON file

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "fuse": {
            "projectType": "application",
            "schematics": {
                "@schematics/angular:component": {
                    "style": "scss"
                }
            },
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "prefix": "app",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
            "aot": true,
                        "outputPath": "dist/fuse",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles.scss"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [],
                        "showCircularDependencies": false
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "aot": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "budgets": [
                                {
                                    "type": "initial",
                                    "maximumWarning": "4mb",
                                    "maximumError": "6mb"
                                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "ec": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
                            "sourceMap": true,
                            "extractCss": true
                        },
                        "hmr": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.hmr.ts"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "fuse:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "fuse:build:production"
                        },
                        "hmr": {
                            "hmr": true,
                            "browserTarget": "fuse:build:hmr"
                        },
                        "ec": {
                            "browserTarget": "fuse:build:ec"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "fuse:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles.scss"
                        ],
                        "scripts": []
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "tsconfig.app.json",
                            "tsconfig.spec.json",
                            "e2e/tsconfig.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "fuse:serve"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "devServerTarget": "fuse:serve:production"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "fuse"
}
```

Comment: How did you solve this?